# WhatsApp and Messenger not working on Auxus BEAST running Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, crashes

I just bought iBerry Auxus BEAST smartphone and I'm facing lots of issues with Lollipop. Apps like WhatsApp, Facebook is not working fine & it crashes rapidly. I could install the apps without any issues, but I cannot use them. Is there any solution to fix this issue?

[image: Screenshot]

```
--Support Info--
 Debug info: +919847081948
 Description: 2.12.5
 Version: 2.12.5
 Exp: 2016-04-22 22:26:45.000+0530
 LC: US
 LG: en
 Context: settings/about
 Carrier: IDEA
 Manufacturer: AUXUS
 Model: AUXUS_BEAST
 OS: 5.0
 Socket Conn: UP
 Radio MCC-MNC: 404-19
 SIM MCC-MNC: 404-19
 CCode: 91 9847081948
 Target: release
 Distribution: play
 Product: AUXUS
 Device: c211_jbl_a128_5m_hd_auxus
 Build: c211_jbl_a128_5m_hd_auxus_20150410
 Kernel: 3.10.61 #6 SMP PREEMPT Thu Apr 16 16:10:15 CST 2015
 Connection: M.O.B.I.L.E. (H.S.P.A.)
 Device ISO8601: 2015-04-26 12:08:23.698+0530
 Phone Type: G.S.M.
 Network Type: H.S.P.A.
 Diagnostic Codes: FE-VC
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings > About AUXUS > Wireless Update` and then click "Check for Updates". You will see a new update there, install the update. It will take 5-10 minutes depending on your WiFi speed or network connection. Once you successfully install the update, your issue will be resolved.

In case you are getting an error message while installing the above update like "Your system was damaged. Wireless update is disabled.", then better reinstall the firmware manually and it will fix the complete issue.

To reinstall the firmware manually, download the firmware on your PC from [iBerry's website](http://iberry.asia/firmware/Auxus-BEAST/Auxus-Beast-20150427.zip). The instructions are given inside the ZIP file in the `Instructions.pdf` file. Follow the instructions to manually install the firmware. Once you manually install the firmware, your issue will be fixed.